# Entity Framework mapping one class across two tables with a condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to map one class to two database tables. I have a Person Class that maps to a Person table and an Address table. My problem is I only want to select the Primary Address Line `(IsPrimary = 1)` of the Address table and I can't find or figure out how to do this.

I'm using Entity Framework v6 CodeFirst and I trying to create the `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` class

The domain class is...

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Primary Address
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string AddressPostCode { get; set; }
}
```

and the database tables look like this...

```
Table: Person
Int PersonId (PK)
Varchar(20) FirstName Not Null
Varchar(20) LastName Not Null

Table: Address
Int         AddressId     (PK)
Int         PersonId      (FK)
Varchar(25) AddressLine1  Null
Varchar(25) AddressLine2  Null
Varchar(25) AddressLine3  Null
Varchar(10) PostCode      Not Null
Bit         IsPrimary     Not Null
```

Basically one Person can have multiple addresses but only One Primary Address.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Entity Framework, probably you have these following classes with a one to many relation:

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddressEntity> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class AddressEntity
{
    public int AddressId  { get; set; }  
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string AddressPostCode { get; set; }
    public bool   IsPrimary{ get; set; }
}
```

And as you mentioned in you'r question, this is the person viewmodel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Primary Address
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string AddressPostCode { get; set; }
}
```

Finally you can use the following linq code:

```
var result = ctx.PersonEntity
.Where(c => c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(X = > X.IsPrimary == true)).ToList();

var personViewModels = result
.Select(c => new PersonViewModel{
PersonId = c.PersonId ,
FirstName = c.FirstName , 
LastName = c.LastName,  
AddressLine1 = c.Addresses != null ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().AddressLine1 : String.Empty , 
AddressLine2 = c.Addresses != null ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().AddressLine2 : String.Empty ,  
AddressLine3 = c.Addresses != null ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().AddressLine3 : String.Empty  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for me.

In my application I have the ability for the admin to define a set of filters for a given search page. Those filters are presented to the user where they can chose to enter their search criteria and submit their search. From this I dynamically create the Linq Where, Select and Order delegates in the code and execute the query.

If I have to split the person and the address entities the Linq statement become significantly more complex hence my need to have them combined as one entity.

Comment: Well, there's really no way to model this by any mapping tricks. This calls for a database view if you want to keep the search mechanism simple.